# Есть ли лицензия на ПО, которая будет распространять его как opensource, но запрещать использование в коммерческих целях?

Tags: лицензирование

Допустим вы написали какой-нибудь свой супер-drupal или 1с-bitrix на C++ или Java, и хотите его выложить на github. Ваше ПО могут использовать все кто хочет - но только не в коммерческих целях. Например любой может склепать себе бложек или развлекательный портальчик, но если какой-нибудь дядя сделает себе интернет-магазин или какой-либо инструмент для управления своим предприятием, то это будет наказуемо.

Есть ли что-либо такое предусмотренное законом или если ваш софт opensource - то все с ним могут делать все что захотят?

**UPD второй случай:**

Допустим вы написали какой-нибудь свой супер-drupal или 1с-bitrix на C++ или Java, и хотите его выложить на github. При этом, вы хотите чтобы ваш софт не модифицировался так, чтоб с него кто-то рубил бабло, он всегда для всех должен быть бесплатен - как бы его не модифицировали. Так же, ваш github-аккаунт должен оставаться единственным источником распространения данного ПО. В случае если кто-то скопирует проект к себе и будет лучше вас его пиарить - он выдаст продукт за свой, и никто и знать не будет настоящего автора. Таких вот случаев тоже хочется избежать. Собственно вопрос и заключается в том, как правильно выложить свой open-source проект, и нужно для этого вести какие-то бумажные законодательные дела, или достаточно залить все на github указав тип лицензии?

Comment: а самый обычный gpl не подходит?

Comment: @KoVadim, а разве gpl запрещает коммерческое использование? IMHO разрешает. GPL только обязывает делать свой   код (коммерческий или нет, не важно), который использует (вот тут вопрос, как именно использует? и тут начинаются разные варианты gpl)  код под GPL открытым. Т.е. суть gpl в распространении открытого для всех нового кода, а не в запрете зарабатывания денег этим кодом.

Comment: @avp, обновил вопрос, добавил второй случай.

Comment: Наверное проще всего написать *свою лицензию*. Например, посмотреть на [это](https://github.com/github/choosealicense.com/blob/gh-pages/README.md), выдрать нужные слова и в пункте `commercial-use - This software and derivatives may be used for commercial purposes.` вставить `NOT`.

Comment: Что же касается запрета копирования и модификации (т.е. Вы единственный владелец этого кода), то можете, наверное, судиться с похитителями (или у Вас есть реальные более действенные методы воздействия?), но (IMHO) **это плохая идея, поскольку информация должна быть свободной**.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>Всё нижеописанное, конечно, зависит от юрисдикции. Я описываю "типичную практику".</sub>

В реалиях цивилизованного мира, уважающего авторское право, всё, что можно делать с вашим продуктом, определяется **вами**, как его автором и **[по умолчанию](http://choosealicense.com/no-license/) всё**, кроме [*свободного использования*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (на Западе аналог: *fair use*) **запрещено**.

Применив **лицензию**, вы расширяете круг разрешённых действий.

---

Собственно, решите сначала для себя: что есть **opensource**? Если интерпретировать термин буквально, то "открытый исходный код". Слово "открытый" открыто (хм) для интерпретации. Что это, "программное обеспечение с исходным кодом, доступным всем желающим"? В этом ключе просто публикация исходного кода разрешает исходный код **читать** (и только потому что он **опубликован**). И всё, на остальное требуется явное разрешение правообладателей.

**И этого *может быть* достаточно.**

**Существуют коммерческие проекты с открытым исходным кодом**, в качестве примера приведу студию *Wolfire Games*. [Они некогда обожглись](http://blog.wolfire.com/2011/02/Counterfeit-Lugaru-on-Apple-s-App-Store-developing), опубликовав исходники одной из своих **игр** (Lugaru) под настолько свободной лицензией (GPL), что кто-то просто скомпилировал исходники и выставил в **Mac App Store** по цене в 10 раз меньшей цены разработчика. И нелегальным (всё-таки) этот факт делало лишь то, что игра состояла не только из собственного скомпилированного исходного кода, но и из ресурсов: звуков, графики, персонажей — права на которые оставались за их авторами, и это было явно оговорено.

С тех пор, на вид, с их играми подобных инцидентов не происходило. А [в лицензии к коду одной из их игр написано следующее](https://github.com/David20321/7DFPS/blob/master/LICENSE.txt):

> All rights reserved by Wolfire Games LLC
> Please email <адрес> if you would like permission to do something with the contents of this repository
>
> Wolfire Games LLC, все права защищены
> Пожалуйста, напишите на <адрес> если вам нужно разрешение что-то сделать с содержимым этого репозитория

---

Но если ваш продукт состоит только из программного кода (или его скомпилированной сборки), **лицензия на код определяет права третьих лиц на действия с продуктом**. А детали уже зависят от конкретной выбранной лицензии. Скажем, GPL или любая другая признаваемая [Open Source Initiative](https://opensource.org/) лицензия даёт права **и на коммерческое использование**.

При всём этом [есть множество историй о нарушениях GPL](http://gpl-violations.org/), как правило забывают (намеренно или нет) приложить экземпляры лицензии или опубликовать свои изменения в GPL-лицензированный код. Особенности GPL.

[Все лицензии, одобренные OSI](https://opensource.org/licenses/category), вашим требованиям не соответствуют. У них [собственное определение "Open Source Definition"](https://opensource.org/osd), в которое включена далеко не только возможность почитать исходники. К примеру, в OSD оговаривается свободное распространение программного обеспечения, в том числе в скомпилированной форме. Вы же собираетесь запретить получение исходного кода из любого места, кроме как вашего Github-репозитория.

---

**Итого.**

Вам придётся либо применить известную лицензию **явно оговаривать исключения**, либо **написать и использовать собственную лицензию**. Оба этих подхода лучше реализовывать совместно с квалифицированным юристом, потому что сформулировать "коммерческое использование" будет непросто.

Но прежде стоит задуматься, нужно ли это. "Выдавать за своё" любая широко используемая лицензия **запрещает** (путём обязательства указывать авторство), разве что кроме передачи в общественное достояние посредством CC0 или аналогов.

Люди, в конце концов, тоже не глупые, и если у некоего платно распространяемого продукта будет бесплатный аналог, пользоваться будут скорее им. Поэтому многие открытые (в смысле OSI) проекты монетизируются **консультациями**, **поддержкой** и **дополнительными подключаемыми модулями**.

**Не держите своих пользователей за идиотов.** А если столкнётесь с фирмой, которая продукт на базе вашего "открытого кода" будет монетизировать (сохранив упоминание о вашем авторстве и не нарушив лицензии), порадуйтесь за неё и напишите на тематические ресурсы несколько статей, где в конце приложите ссылку на ваш репозиторий и на сайт фирмы, этим продуктом занимающейся. Получится комичная ситуация.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Вы пишите `применить известную лицензию либо написать и использовать собственную лицензию`. Это каким образом делается? Заверяется ли данная лицензия документально? Либо достаточно файла `license` в репозитории?

Comment: @sanu0074 вот по этому вопросу вам лучше к юристу. Принятая практика это файл лицензии в репозитории, реже кусок лицензии в каждом файле с исходным кодом в комментариях, в шапке. Как я понимаю, основное назначение сего действа -- обеспечить неминуемость ознакомления с лицензией перед работой с кодом.

Answer (score 6):

Идея изначально провальна. Вы никогда не сможете формализовать ваше "коммерческое использование" в адекватной форме. Вы вообще задумывались над тем, что вы под этим словосочетанием подразумеваете?

Вы пишете:

> Например любой может склепать себе бложек или развлекательный портальчик, но если какой-нибудь дядя сделает себе интернет-магазин или какой-либо инструмент для управления своим предприятием, то это будет наказуемо.

Бложек? А если я художник и пишу в одной из блогозаписей про свои расценки — это коммерческое использование?

Портальчик? А если в углу сайта размещён рекламный блок — это коммерческое использование?

Управление предприятием? А если я создаю бесплатный сервис и даю всем инструменты для управления их предприятиями — это коммерческое использование?

Когда определитесь, что вы имеете в виду, уже можно будет о чём-то говорить.

---

Впрочем, для начала определитесь, чего вы хотите от этого самого опенсорса. Сорцы открывают по разным причинам:

- Добиться максимальной популярности. Чем больше бесплатных пользователей, тем больше популярность, тем больше про вас узнают те, кто готов платить.
- Упростить создание расширений. На случай, когда лень писать качественную документацию.
- Доказать качество кода. Посмотрел клиент на код — остался доволен.
- И так далее.

Допустим, вы хотите завоевать популярность. В этом случае необходимо учесть, что чем больше препятствий вы чините на пути потребителей (необходимость раскрывать сорцы, запрет коммерческого использования и т. п.), тем меньше бонусов от открытых исходников.

"Стандартных" лицензий с запретом коммерческого использования не существует, поэтому вам придётся писать свою лицензию, а это на порядки сложнее, чем вы думаете. Кроме того, это поставит крест на нормальной интеграции кода с разными лицензиями из-за несовместимости лицензий.

Можно применить и хитрую стратегию со сменой лицензии, правда будьте готовы к тому, что вас будут ненавидеть.

---

В целом, советую начать с какой-нибудь либеральной лицензии типа MIT/BSD или Apache, в крайнем случае с вирусной GPL, в случае паранойи — с AGPL. Они решат ваши проблемы с атрибуцией.

При этом вы увидите, нужен ли вообще ваш код хоть кому-то. И вот когда будет популярность, уже можно будет начинать думать, что делать. Лицензию на старые версии вы отменить не сможете, конечно, но дальше можно будет развиваться под другой лицензией.

Если же вы нагородите заборов заранее, то никогда не узнаете, какой реально спрос.